# Highchart Polar or Wind rose Scatter

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to create a presentation of data using highcharts Polar and scatter. 
or how to create a highchart wind rose and scatter presentation.

I played with the configuration of the windrose chart on this link 
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-wind-rose

for simplicity, the project information to be presented are as follows:

no | project owner | project type | project color

**where:**

1. Project type could be 1 of 10 values (p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10).
   The exact naming of these values is shown in the attached image.
2. Project color could be 1 of 2 values (blue, red).
3. An owner could have one or more projects, same type and color.

The goal is to show on one single chart the information of the projects (as in this below image).

[image]

the image on the left shows (windrose) shows what I am trying to convert to the image on the right Polar scatter chart.

The purpose; 
so the person looking at the chart can read the follow:
1- distribution of projects by type.
2- distribution of projects by color 
3- distribution of projects by owner (if possible)

any help to guide me on how to use the polar or windrose to achieve this presentation would be appreciated.

Comment: See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/A8PN3/ and attach mockup as image, beacuse your is not clear.

Comment: thanks @SebastianBochan for your answer. i will edit to add more details.

Comment: @SebastianBochan pls look at the attached images and let me know if it is clear enough or needs further explanation. thx

Comment: Its clear, so based on my chart you can achieve this.

Comment: @SebastianBochan yes indeed, using the series and adding scatter in your code helped a lot. thanks for the tip :)